# PHP Rest API Endpoint Function Will Echo Stop Further Processing

Tags: php, rest

```
class REST {
  // this section is from http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/02/simple-php-mysql-rest-api-sample-example-tutorial/
  public function response($data,$status){
    $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
    $this->set_headers();
    echo $data;
    exit;
  }
}

class API extends REST {
  private function create_booking(){    

    if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
      echo $this->response('Method Not Acceptable',406);
    }

    /*pseudocode for processing data if method is POST*/
    Find whether record exists.
    If exist {
      set $message = "record found"
    } else {
      If not exist, insert record
      set $message = "record inserted"
    }
    echo $this->response($message,200);
  }
}
```

I would like to know, if let's say I have an API end point using the above method, when user is not using POST, will system stop processing after echo the error 406, or it will still continue after existing IF statement.

I have users submitting a new booking to this end point several times due to server did not response a message. End up I have duplicate bookings in my database.

What could lead to such incident?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you should not be echoing it. Rather, response should have the status code, which will stop further processing of the request.

Comment: You should exit after `echo $this->response('Method Not Acceptable',406);`.

Comment: Everything was copied from http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/02/simple-php-mysql-rest-api-sample-example-tutorial/ and then modify.
Should I just exit after echo for each IF ELSE condition also?

Comment: From what I've seen, it's more common to return the response rather than echo it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will execute further, but you need to stop further execution. You can add a simple `return` in *your method* below the echo message to quit the method:

```
if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
  echo $this->response('Method Not Acceptable',406);
  return;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer exit to prevent any other output.

Comment: @MarkusZeller If inside a method, exit is a bad idea, especially if you are using a framework. Regarding extra output, that would be a mismanagement of flow of execution for an incoming request.

Comment: I'll give this a try @vivek_23.
Thanks everybody!

Comment: But if the Framework does output after the return, it also bad. I HATE FRAMEWORKS. Exit **is** a good way and used million times in CLI. Alternative throwing an Exception.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Exits stops the entire execution. I have never seen a framework adding additional output without developer intervention.

Comment: Let's say a template engine is involved, then it is not impossible more output will follow, just because a request header was set. As I said, in CLI it is very common or Exceptions should be thrown to handle such cases. Just my cents.